# Did Saul poison Brock?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad* Saul has been shown at Andrea's new house, where he delivers Jesse's money directly to Andrea. Both her and Brock are familiar with him, we even see him conversing with Brock. 
Also later in the 5th season, Walt randomly shows up on their door-step, I don't recall Jesse ever telling him where they live...it connects the dots a little, it would also explain *how* Brock was poisoned.
Saul gave him Lily of the Valley

> The doctors and Jesse believed that Brock came across the flower growing naturally and ate some poisonous berries.

And how often would a kid question someone they knew? All Saul would have to do was hold out his hand and watch him eat the poison. It parallels nicely too, with Jesse's all too foreboding words "*you're just feeding them hamburgers, just like every time.*  Also note that Saul is distant with Walt throughout the 5th season, and uncomfortable whenever asked to perform a task for him.

So did Saul poison Brock?

Comment: @DanielBeck It's the other way around. The question you've linked to was posted today, but this one is from 2013.

Comment: @JBentley The new question has a definitive answer and is therefore more useful to readers.

Answer (score 5):

I remember a meeting scene of Walter and Saul, where Saul mentioned that he stole the cigarette from Jesse. Saul even mentioned that he doesn't know the intention of Walter and didn't even know that he was going to poison Brock; from that conversation, it is clear that Walter poisoned Brock.

Also Saul is a kind of person which can get address of anybody easily because *he knows a person, who knows a person...*, and Saul was uncomfortable working with Walter because Walter poisoned Brock and Saul was somewhere responsible for it too because he helped in getting the cigarette.

Even confirmed in this [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14222/is-walt-really-sorry-for-poisoning-brock) from season 5 episode 13.